# Getting error when I try to open the Laravel file from localhost

Tags: php

Hello everybody recently I have downloaded laravel 3.2.10. But when I try open the package from the local host I get the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'yield' (T_YIELD), expecting '('
>   in /opt/lampp/htdocs/2016/laravel-3.2.10/laravel/helpers.php on line
>   563.

Please help, I am new to the Software field. So kindly bear my ignorances....

Comment: What version of PHP you have because if it is older version than `PHP 5.3` yoi will get also that error.

Answer (score 0):

What version of PHP do you have installed? For older versions the Laravel function called `yield()` collides with a reserved name. Either upgrade both your PHP and Laravel versions or use this version of Laravel where `yield()` gets overwritten as `_yield()`:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/3298407238fd3e212cdf8d829adc6f519b941052